# using location api in android

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, location, android-location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user’s current location in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

I have studies the location api for android and tried the basic apps which have the use of the locationChanged method and provide a simplest solution to keep track of use location.

How can keep track of the following actions of user in the same context

- user entering a new location
- user leaving the current location

and also about the following factors :

- the new location is not within say x meters of the old location
- and the attributes required for comparing the last and new location

Answer (score 0):

This isn't bad. The official Android SDK on this matter is actually pretty good. [Official Google Documentation on it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Basically the interface it uses runs functions as each one of these situations arises. So, onLocationChanged gets called whenever the location changes according to whatever parameter fires that off. Also, I would recommend just playing with the different provider types

The hardest part is the distance part. There's equations out there to calculate distance using longitude and latitudes.

From the documentation:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```